# What does this error (NSInvalidArgumentException) mean?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Got this error for a Tetris game that I'm making. Not really sure how to upload the Xcode project to GitHub as I get denied as I don't have access so sorry for no context. None of this error seems to actually make sense to me, its just a random collection of numbers and some recognisable phrases like 'SpriteKit' or 'UIKit'.

```
2017-05-15 10:09:10.942 Tetris[2258:77198] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Setting this node as parent would create a loop: <SKNode> name:'(null)' position:{6, -6} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{12, -412}, {200, 400}}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa4dd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cacb21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fab72b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010cfe3134 -[SKNode(setParent) setParent:] + 87
    4   SpriteKit                           0x000000010cfdc376 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 230
    5   SpriteKit                           0x000000010cfdc26f -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    6   Tetris                              0x000000010c4bafe0 _TFC6Tetris9GameScenecfT4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 1376
    7   Tetris                              0x000000010c4bb080 _TFC6Tetris9GameSceneCfT4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 64
    8   Tetris                              0x000000010c4c23f2 _TFC6Tetris18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 274
    9   Tetris                              0x000000010c4c3222 _TToFC6Tetris18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d368a3d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d368e70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d2324b5 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d232c06 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d246519 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d1bef8d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c50ed -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c226d -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116a4b6cb __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116a4b544 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116a4b8cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9f2761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9d798c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9d6e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9d6884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c0aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c6c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  Tetris                              0x000000010c4c858f main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001109fd68d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: The displayed error *reason* is quite meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from the [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsexceptionname/1415426-invalidargumentexception), `NSInvalidArgumentException` is:

> Name of an exception that occurs when you pass an invalid argument to
>   a method, such as a nil pointer where a non-nil object is required.

It should also has a *reason* of why it occurred.

---

Referring to your case the **reason** is:

> Setting this node as parent would create a loop: 
>   name:'(null)' position:{6, -6} scale:{1.00, 1.00}
>   accumulatedFrame:{{12, -412}, {200, 400}}

Trying to debug the crashed scene, the reason should be clear enough for detecting what is the reason of causing the crash.

Comment: Do you mind going into a bit more detail? When I search `Setting this node as parent would create a loop` on google nothing comes up explaining what this actually means or how I would fix it.